# Getting Error ImportError Cannot import Name 'Window' from [dir]

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

Actually i made a GUI.py and wanted to make it a module

the directory is like this:

```
\lib\site-packages\GUI\ __init__.py --> this file is empty 
\lib\site-packages\GUI\__main__.py --> this file contains the classes
```

```py
the code in __main__.py is:
```

```py
from tkinter import *

class Window():
    def __init__(self):
        super(window,self).__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
        self.main = Tk()

    def title(self,title="tk"):
        self.main.title(title)

    def run(self):
        self.main.mainloop()
```

the code in another file is:

```py
from GUI import Window
a = Window()
a.run()
```

However this generates Error:

`ImportError: cannot import name 'Window' from 'GUI' (C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\GUI\__init__.py)`

How can i fix this?
thanx in advance!

Comment: try putting `from __main__ import *` in this file: `\lib\site-packages\GUI\ __init__.py`. maybe it fixes your problem.

Comment: @Tabaraei No it still causes the Error

Comment: @Sujay how do i initialize the class i did `a = Window()` so that should initialize it

Comment: I mean you should put ```def __init___(self)``` after ```class Window()```

Comment: @Sujay i did that too but not fixed my problem i also edited my question

Comment: ```super.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)```. Try adding this to ```__init__()``` ```self,*args,**kwargs```

Comment: Also remove ```()``` from ```class Window()```

Comment: Still same @Sujay

Answer (score 0):

Oh sorry to trouble you i found out my mistake!

I made them opposite

what i did:

1. Renamed The `__main__.py` to `__init__.py` and `__init__.py` to `__main__.py`
2. and as `@Tabaraei` Said i added `from __init__ import *` in `__main__.py`

Fixed My problem Thank you all!